# I set up a recurring payment in real time with my credit card and then when I log in to CIviCRM it says incomplete transaction

Tags: civicontribute

As a donor, I go to uwoec.org and hit the donate button. I fill out all information and I click for a recurring payment and put in my credit card information and hit submit.  I get a message saying I will get a receipt in my email once the transaction has been processed.
As an admin for United way of Etowah County, I login to look at my donation information and it shows my name, amount that will recur monthly and the status says Pending (incomplete transaction) with no additional information.

Please help.

Comment: Which payment processor are you using?
Are regular non-recurring transaction being processed?

Comment: did a payment get set up in the payment processor? if so then often a payment processor needs to be told the return point so it knows how to send back the correct info - otherwise civi never gets told if it succeeded or not

Answer (score 1):

Every processor is different but all must have a process that 'talks back' to CiviCRM with status update.  Otherwise CiviCRM doesn't know if the payment succeeded.

The URL that you must put inside your processor normally looks like this:

> https://yoursite.org/civicrm/payment/ipn/1

Please check the configuration and instructions for your processor